# When I'm trying convert OpenCV4.1 program to wasm following error is comming

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, emscripten

When I'm trying to convert OpenCV4.1 program to wasm with the following command an error occured:

```
sudo /home/xxx/Documents/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/em++ -std=c++11 -s WASM=1 -I ../../../../usr/local/include/opencv4/ test.cpp  -o test.html
```

**The following error is coming:**

```
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv11namedWindowERKNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEi
warning: To disable errors for undefined symbols use `-s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0`
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv13destroyWindowERKNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imreadERKNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEi
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6imshowERKNSt3__212basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEERKNS_11_InputArrayE
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv7waitKeyEi
error: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv
Error: Aborting compilation due to previous errors
shared:ERROR: '/home/kaushal/Documents/emsdk/node/12.9.1_64bit/bin/node /home/kaushal/Documents/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/src/compiler.js /tmp/tmpxI4v0X.txt' failed (1)
```

**Simple test code:**

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

 Mat image = imread("./1.png");

 // Check for failure
 if (image.empty())
 {
  cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl;
  cin.get();
  return -1;
 }

 String windowName = "test";

 namedWindow(windowName);

 imshow(windowName, image);

 waitKey(0);

 destroyWindow(windowName);

 return 0;
}
```

Please help me if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: You haven't shown your code, so how do you expect anyone to be able to tell you why it gives a certain result?

Comment: All example code needs to go *in* the question. *Not* behind external links.

Comment: I have added code in the question.